# Undefined method `set_primary_key' for Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, class-table-inheritance

I have a problem with using [Class-Table-Inheritance](https://github.com/brunofrank/class-table-inheritance) gem. When I try check in console the correctness of inheritance console return this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `set_primary_key' for Client (call
>   'Client.connection' to establish a connection):Class

I define primary key for Client, but there is still error.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass
 self.table_name = 'people'

end
```

Model Client

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   inherits_from :person
   self.primary_key = "person_id"
end
```

Part of migration file CreatePeople

```
create_table :people do |t|
  t.string :pesel, null: false
  t.string :first_name, null: false
  t.string :last_name, null: false
  t.string :email, null: false
  t.date :date_of_birth, null: false
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Part of migration file CreateClients

```
create_table :clients, :inherits => :person do |t|
end
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: This gem has no dev activity in the last 5 years.

Comment: @BroiSatse Do you know any gem to implement class table inheritance?

Comment: You can have a look at dbview_cti: https://github.com/mvdamme/dbview_cti. It is actually so cool it creates database views for speed and glory. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse I tried use this gem, but it's create properly view, not table in database...

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. You need to create class tables on your own, it will handle getting the data out of mutliple tables. What was your particular problem with it?

Comment: @BroiSatse I want to imitate my entities diagram using code first. I would like to use class type inheritance, and I thought that this gem is the best way to do this. But now I feel confuse...